# Can`t make susy start working

Tags: sass, compass, susy-compass, susy, susy-sass

I wanted to start a project with Sass / Compass and for grid I want to use susy.
Installed sass -v 3.4.24
          Compass 1.0.3

All good and working. After I installed susy 3.0.6 and not working then I tried  2.2.12, and use the simple code `body { @include container(80em); }`

I get the `Undefined mixin 'container'` all the time.

What do i do wrong?

Comment: How are you importing sussy? You have to use @import "susy"; in order to load the mixins associated with it

Comment: yes. and i also have in config.rb 'require 'susy'

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend using Compass, since it is no longer maintained and Susy 3 no longer supports it. With Susy 2, it should work, but you will have to require and import Susy before it will work. Installing is not enough.

There are some brief instructions in the [Susy docs](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/install/#id1).

Specifically, those commands add a `require 'susy'` line to the compass config, and an `import 'susy'` line in the Sass/Scss.

Since Compass is no longer maintained, I'm a bit fuzzy on exactly how the config/require is supposed to look.

Comment: i have require 'susy' and also @import "susy" in my main scss file. I followed the instruction and nothing. same error. susy is not working

Comment: ok, this is likely a problem in the Compass setup, and compass is not maintained. It has not been maintained for several years now. I strongly recommend not using Compass.